# Looping through files in a folder, code breaks if statement is false a singular time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an excel macro to loop through files in a folder, I'm  looping through files looking for a particular string in the file name, and if it finds a file with that string in its name, it sets a certain cell value to 1.

However, it seems as though after it doesn't find the file one time, it will never find another one again, and will never set another cell to 1. I have checked the test directory I'm using manually to ensure that it's not actually the case that no files after that exist.

Here's what I have:

```
'loop through files in folder checking if value in B column is present


Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
file = Dir("dummydirectory")



Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("B164:B1533")
Dim targetcell As Range


For Each cell In rng
 Do While (file <> "")
   Set targetcell = cell.Offset(0, 12) 'sets targetcell 12 columns to the right of the original (B -> N)
      If InStr(file, cell.Value) > 0 Then
         targetcell.Value = 1
         Exit Do
      End If
     file = Dir
  Loop
  
Next cell
End Sub

'current issues:
'as soon as the the if statement is false once, it will never set another cell to 1
'ie: as soon as one cell is not set to 1, it stops working essentially
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with where
`file = Dir`
was placed, I put it outside the do loop, in the if statement, and nothing seems to work.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It does what you tell it: `Exit Do` so it exits the `Do` loop. But I don't think you want that.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie In fact I had tried removing the Exit Do at one point, but it actually made it only work on the very first cell, and then after that it stopped. The idea was once it found a match, it set the cell to 1, and then it moved on to the next cell. IE: it loops through the folders looking for a name containing the value of Cell B164, once it finds a match, it exits the do loop and goes to Next cell, and the process repeats. I have a feeling that I'm not actually resetting the file to have it search from the top and eventually it just runs out of files to check and stops.

Comment: Ah, I see. The `Exit Do` is indeed fine. But after the `Loop` you must reset `file` by doing again `file = Dir("dummydirectory")`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That was it, thank you so much, you've saved me an afternoon of headaches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `file` after each `Loop`. The following is a more efficient way of doing that:

```
For Each cell In rng
 file = Dir("dummydirectory")
 Do 
   Set targetcell = cell.Offset(0, 12) 'sets targetcell 12 columns to the right of the original (B -> N)
      If InStr(file, cell.Value) > 0 Then
         targetcell.Value = 1
         Exit Do
      End If
     file = Dir
  While (file <> "")
  
Next cell
```